# Change the position of a gate in Qiskit for better representation

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm using Qiskit to demonstrate some circuits, and I want to change the position of some gates for better representation.

For example, look at this circuit: [image]

I'd like for the last $R_x(\frac{-\pi}{2})$ to align with the last Hadamard gate. Is there a way to do this without using barriers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `justify=` parameter might help.

```
qc.draw('mpl', reverse_bits=True, justify='right')
```

[image]

Other option is to add the `barrier` and then remove them from the plot (though that will skip all the barriers)

```
...
qc.barrier(range(4))
qc.h(3)
qc.rx(-pi/2, 0)
qc.draw('mpl', reverse_bits=True, plot_barriers=False)
```

[image]

Comment: The adding barrier then removing it seems like a good solution. Thanks a lot!